# gps tracking on custom map in an IOS app

Tags: ios, maps

Well, I know that this is not a strongly programmatical question but I didn't know where else to ask and I didn't find anything similar. I want to create a GPS tracking app. I have done much of the functionality and I am using Google Maps. However, for the areas that I am interested and I want to use the app, it happens not to be exact in the Google maps (they are not conventional roads but for example hiking paths in some mountains). I have created a custom photo/image of this path and I want an elegant way of tracking in this custom image that would be used as a map.

I am thinking of this:

Once the location of the user is identified and the place that the user is is loaded (the custom image), since I know the path and I can find the lat/long itself (for example by going there by myself), I will fetch the user's lat/long any time and compare it with the path. Then I will draw on that image the path. Here are my questions:

1. Do you think this is complicated or is there a better way ?
2. What will happen with the GPS accuracy. Do you think it might be a problem?

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768253/android-gps-tracking-with-a-custom-map) which wants to do something similar. Do you think, an approach using mapTiler [link](http://www.maptiler.org) would be better or not? Might it be rejected by Apple?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a KVO on GMSMap.mylocation and this will be called everytime google map location is updated. Here you need to check if the location identified is within a range +/- 20m of your path and then show the image.